# Input variable runs code after third attempt

Tags: python

I'm creating a test 'text adventure' game, and code is run based on the input() text, but when I try out the code and type in text for the input variable it doesn't run until I have tried a couple of times.

I've tried moving the location of the input() but it does the same thing.

```
def Inputs():
   while True:
    global Hour
    global Wait
    if input() == 'search' and Wait == False:
        for x in range(1):
          print('You got +',random.randint(0,5), 'food and +', random.randint(0,5), 'water')
        Hour = Hour + 1
        Wait = True
        t.start

    if input() == 'search' and Wait == True:
          print('You decide to wait before looking again.')


    if input() == 'search' and Wait == True:
      print('You decide to wait before looking again.')


    if input() == 'light' and Day == True:
      print('You light a fire.')      

    if input() == 'light' and Day == False:
      print('You cannot light a fire, it\'s day.')


    if input() == 'info':
      print(Info())


    if input() == 'craft':
      print('Test Text (Finish)')


    if input() == 'help':
      print(Instructions)
```

It should display 'You light a fire.'

Comment: What's the point of `for x in range(1):`?

Comment: `t.start` doesn't do anything. If that's a function, you need to call it with parentheses. `t.start()`

Comment: Each time you call `input()`, it waits for a *new* input.  You want to ask for input *once* and save that into a variable.

Comment: Each time you execute `if input() == 'something'` it's going to wait for another line from the user. You should call it once and save the result in a variable, then test the variable against all the different commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `input() == XXX` the interpreter ask for a new input so the loop takes 8 inputs before looping back.

You should call `input` once and store result in a variable.